# How to re add data that I just dropped from a data frame?

Tags: r

I recently dropped data from my meansleep data set using [-c(3,12), ]

I now am realizing I want that those columns to still be in my data set. How do I re add this data?

The variables were Id:
User, TotalMinutesAsleep, sleep_hours
3, 412, 8.44
12, 429, 7.15

Comment: Have you overwritten original data using <- ?

Comment: Yes, meansleep <- meansleep[-c(3,12), ]

Comment: Simply assign to new named object.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete your data, and overwrite the name of your old data like this...

```r
head(mtcars)
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

mtcars <- mtcars[-c(1:10)]

head(mtcars)
#>                   carb
#> Mazda RX4            4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag        4
#> Datsun 710           1
#> Hornet 4 Drive       1
#> Hornet Sportabout    2
#> Valiant              1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

... then it's gone. You need to import your original data again and start your analysis over.

This is why it's a good idea to:

1. Use R scripts for your analysis code, so it's easy to rerun if you need to start over
2. Save your data with different names if you're not aboslutely sure you want to delete it:

```r
head(mtcars)
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

new_data <- mtcars[-c(1:10)]

# New dataframe:
head(new_data)
#>                   carb
#> Mazda RX4            4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag        4
#> Datsun 710           1
#> Hornet 4 Drive       1
#> Hornet Sportabout    2
#> Valiant              1

# Original data still here
head(mtcars)
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>